# How to get a warning before sending from a given account?

Tags: thunderbird

At university,
I have my personal email account and my institutional email account both linked onto thunderbird.

This is useful, for obvious reasons: I can check my personal communications without wasting time loading up an separate client.

However, I rarely want to sent an email from thuderbird (on the university PC) from my personal account. Emails from my personal account don't have the university name in the address, and have my nickname as the Sender. Further more replies obviously go to that personal account. Since I am generally sending professional correspondence from my uni PC, I don't want this.

One option would be to just remove the STMP server from the account -- so it can receive but not send.
But then I couldn't send if I wanted to.

What I really want is for it to pop up a warning before sending, saying:
"You are sending from account X, are you sure you don't want to send from account Y?" 
or similar.

Is there functionality to do this in thunderbird?

I am using windows 7, and thunderbird 38.0 (latest)

Comment: Please add some details about the Operative System and the Thunderbird version...

Comment: @Hastur Done. But for my own education: why would my thunderbird version (isn't it safe to assume latest?), and more significantly my Operating System matter (given that thunderbird does not change based on your OS) ?

Comment: People can have installed different versions; in the porting it's  always possible that some minor difference appears. Moreover this question can be still seen in future  when the program can be totally different and the solution to your question, posted and effective today, can be obsolete. To know the versions of the program and of the operative system can help to write a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the "[correct-identity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/correct-identity/)" add-on might work for you.
It pretty much does as you request. Download and then install from the thunderbird addon manager. The settings can be set from within the addons specific options available in the addons manager once its installed. With it I was able to force newly composed emails to all come from the default account rather than the account last looked at. Replies still go back against the accounts to which the original was sent.

Comment: Awesome!  Exactly what I needed.  My TB at the office was configured for two domains, work and home.  All too often I would send from my home domain to a work recipient.  After installing Correct Identity, I just entered domain names for each identity and now TB corrects the identity as soon as I provide a recipient.  I only wish I had searched for solution long ago.

Answer (score 2):

I always hated the fact that Thunderbird chooses which account to send based upon wherever your cursor happens to be, especially since I have somewhere around 15 or so different email addresses in my personal Thunderbird.  Each account is for a different purpose, and it can become a headache to keep track where in the long list of accounts my cursor happens to have last clicked.  I feel your pain.  I know I have accidentally sent emails from the wrong accounts on multiple occasions--which usually leads to people sending me emails to more than one address at a time and having to deal with multiple copies of each email.  No bueno.

I found and highly recommend the add-on **Identity Chooser**, which turns the "Write" button in Thunderbird into a drop-down list.  That way you know for sure that you are choosing which account to send from every time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can search some setting around it

> When you write a new message, Thunderbird uses the default identity for the account you are working in. When you reply to a message, Thunderbird uses the identity that matches the address the message was originally sent to, if it can find a match in the account you are working in. Otherwise it uses the default identity. Set **mailnews.reply_to_self_check_all_ident** to **true** using the Config editor if you want it to check the identities for all accounts when replying.

Reference:

- [Multiple identities per e-mail account](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Suite_:_FAQs_:_Mail_Aliases)

Comment: That doesn't sound like it does what i describe at all? That sounds like it only interact with when you are replying.

Comment: I should agree, but your question (you said) was originated by a need (or an ease) and this answer can suggest you an alternative path to fulfill it. By knowing and setting the default behaviour of your program you can be sure that 1). It will start new mail with University account __else you have to do an action__. 2). It will automatically answer with the original account to each mail __else you have to do an action__. Moreover it suggests a way to access to the program settings so that  you can search among them if it exists something suitable...

Comment: On the computer I'm working on there is no thunderbird installed. I'm sorry I cannot give you more help but only some directions. In the hope it can be enough or a base to continue.